# Admin Security, Lockout Attempts, PW Resets

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, security

A [recent article](https://magento.com/security/best-practices/5-immediate-actions-protect-against-brute-force-attacks) went out about improving admin security.  In it they suggest setting the maximum PW resets and Lockout Time, and for Magento 1.x, this is supposed to live under **System > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security**.  Unless I'm mistaken, this doesn't exist in Open Source 1.x.  Is this an enterprise only feature?  The article is actually tagged with "Open Source", so this should be specific to the OS version, yet these settings don't exist in my copy.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed an Enterprise only feature